# Getting the right calc for multiple if statement in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, business-intelligence

I’m trying to write a if then statement on tableau but I might be missing something it’s a multiple comparison
What I have now
If {Receive campus match } = false then ‘0’
Else
If { matches lag} = true then true else false
Else
If { days difference between goods planned vs shipped} < = 0
Then { fixed .......} there’s an LOD
ELSE ‘0’
End
End
End
But it not correct ! Help will be needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not uploaded any data/screenshot, it is very difficult to understand your problem, yet I can see a few errors in your proposed calculation.

Your proposed calculation, if broken into phrases becomes like this-

```
line-1  If {Receive campus match } = false 
line-2  then ‘0’ 
line-3  Else If { matches lag} = true 
line-4  then true 
line-5  else false 
line-6  Else If { days difference between goods planned vs shipped} < = 0 
line-7  Then { fixed .......} there’s an LOD 
line-8  ELSE ‘0’ 
line-9  End End End
```

Problem-1:  In tableau there is `ELSEIF` and not `ELSE IF`

Problem-2: You cannot start a new `else if` (sic!) (line-6) once an `else` (line-5) has been provided

Problem-3: Why three `END` in line-9?

Basically the syntax of IF THEN ELSE IF ELSE END goes like this...

```
IF    <Condition>
Then <Result 1>
ELSEIF  <condition 2>
then <Result>
... Repeat ELSEIF and THEN here, if you have several conditions

ELSE <last result corresponding to last false condition>
END
```